How can I make this IP table rule persistent?
I use the following to block a domain with IP tables on a Linux system:
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "account.jetbrains.com" --algo kmp -j REJECT

How can I make this persist across reboots?

Install the iptables persistent firewall service. On Ubuntu, for example:
sudo apt install iptables-persistent -y

This service lets you save your rule sets and reload them when the machine reboots. During installation you'll have the option to specify where to save the rules sets in files for both IPv4 and IPv6. If the rule in your question has already been added, it'll be saved. If not, you can manually add it to the file and reload the service:
sudo service netfilter-persistent reload

You can also add it using the iptables command as above and the saving the rules manually by running "netfilter-persistent":
sudo service netfilter-persistent save


-You just need define the new rules and then record the actual/actives rules or change the rules " editing files of rules!" using the follow commands
for Debian/Ubuntu distros

iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 

or

 iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6

for RHEL/CentOS disrtos

iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables

With this you just record the active rules of IPTables, you can left the rules with automatic loading editing the files:

/etc/iptables/rules.v4

or

/etc/iptables/rules.v6

You can define rules for iptables and use the iptables-save command to store the defined rules in a file easily using the command:

iptables-save > /root/ipt.rules.saved

And then if you want to apply and restore the rules saved in the file you can simply use the command:

cat /root/ipt.rules.saved | iptables-restore

with this the iptables will read the rules written in the file and apply them to the system, ok!
with this the iptables just read the rules from the file and apply at the system.
